Why my redis sentinel cluster is always writeable?
I've deployed a 3 node Redis cluster along with sentinel, using bitnami helm chart. A service is deployed that load balances among Redis nodes on port 6379, that one of them is supposed to be writeable at a time.
So I connect to this service using kubectl port-forwarding and redis-cli. No matter how many times I tried it, it was always letting me perform write operations like set foo bar.
It is a bit odd, since it seems that the load balancer always connects to the writable node.
Am I missing something? Can I safely use this service with the real workload as well?

Note that kubectl port-forward service/... doesn't actually use the Service; instead, it looks up the Pods connected to the Service and it port-forwards to a single one of the Pods.  If it's picked the writable replica, that's consistent with the behavior you see.

@DavidMaze But this is happening every single time that I do this.
